# ClojureScript date-time library

Tags: date, datetime, clojurescript

I'd like to do some basic, but not very basic date-related operations on ClojureScript, like getting the days between two dates.  There is [clj-time](https://github.com/clj-time/clj-time) which is a wrapper around [Joda time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/), so it's Clojure only.  I'm also aware of the [date classes in Google Closure Library](http://docs.closure-library.googlecode.com/git/namespace_goog_date.html).  There are many possibilites for JavaScript, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/802861/javascript-date-manipulation-library or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/996995/javascript-date-time-library-recommendations.  I wonder if there is an idiomatic ClojureScript way for this.  If there is no such beast, I wonder which JavaScript library would be the best candidate for wrapping.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

http://momentjs.com is easy to use for date arithmetic.

For example, the difference between two dates, in number of days:

```
(defn mom []
  (let [log (fn [& args] (.log js/console (apply str args)))
        days-ago (fn [n] (.subtract (js/moment) "days" n))]
    (log {:difference (.diff (days-ago 7) (days-ago 28) "days")})))

(mom) ==> {:difference 21}
```

Comment: Be aware that Moment uses mutable dates.

Answer (score 17):

Too late, but for those who come by search, there is [cljs-time](https://github.com/andrewmcveigh/cljs-time) library.

Answer (score 1):

The project I'm working at the moment uses moment.js. It works pretty much ok with clojurescript. I recommend to check that out.

Answer (score 1):

If you want something cross-platform, try [juxt/tick](https://github.com/juxt/tick)

Regarding days between two dates, this seems to work on both platforms (calling into the [underlying](https://js-joda.github.io/js-joda/manual/LocalDate.html#distance-on-the-timeline) [libraries](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#until-java.time.temporal.Temporal-java.time.temporal.TemporalUnit-) for `.until`):

```
(require '[tick.alpha.api :as t])
(require '[tick.core])
(.until (t/new-date 2019 1 1) (t/new-date 2019 3 5) (tick.core/unit-map :days))
;=> 63
```

Answer (score 0):

For date picking, the react-select project has an experimental [date picker](https://react-select.com/advanced#experimental) with fuzzy date support. We're using the regular `react-select` component wrapped in cljs, seems to work pretty well.